# Create directory under local app data

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have application written in C/C++ and it needs to create a folder and file under the local app directory.  When I call CreateDirectory the result is False and the directory is never created.  What am I missing?

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL,CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA|CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE, NULL, 0, szPath)))
{
    PathAppend(szPath,_T("\\FredDir\\backupfirmware\\"));
    bool result = CreateDirectory(szPath, NULL);
}
```

As near as I can tell this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateDirectory` can't create several levels worth of directories at once. You need to create them one by one - first `FredDir`, then `backupfirmware` under that.